# Bitemporal with Arangodb

Tags: arangodb, bi-temporal

Are there any patterns or examples available for doing bitemporal modelling with ArangoDB? I am evaluating my options for choosing a database and ArangoDB seems to have the required features.

Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we currently don't know existing examples of how to do that in Arangodb.

However, Reading over [the code project article about Bitemporal Database Design](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17637/Bitemporal-Database-Table-Design-The-Basics) You would do similar in ArangoDB - have two attributes with start and end-date.

The problem of this aproach would however be, that you can't combine a range over two attributes in one skiplist index. One could probably work around this by specifying a range on the start attribute to be within a query range. A second filter would then sort out the documents that don't fulfill the end timestamp:

```
FOR item IN testCollection 
   FILTER item.startTime < @startTimeMin AND item.startTime > @startTimeMax 
   FILTER item.endTime < @endTimeMax
  RETURN item
```

With the bind values:

```
{
  startTimeMin: '2016.01.15',
  startTimeMax: '2016.01.30',
  endTimeMax: '2016.01.25
 }
```

However, if you could be a bit more detailed about your usecase, probably a more precise answer can be made.